# Mathematica 10 fails to calculate integral that Mathematica 9 can handle

Tags: symbolic, version-10

The following:

```
Mass/2  Integrate[(r^2 + Rotation^2 (2 - Cos[θ]^2))/(r^2 + Rotation^2
  Cos[θ]^2)^2 Sin[θ], {r, r1, ∞}, {θ, 0, π},
  Assumptions -> {r1 > 0 && Rotation >= 0}] // Simplify
```

returns

> ```
> (1/(32 Rotation))Mass (-16 ArcTan[r1/Rotation] + 1/(2 r1^2)(16 π r1^2 +
> 32 r1 Rotation + π Rotation^2 + 8 π r1^2 Log[r1] +
> 4 ArcTan[Rotation/r1] (7 Rotation^2 - 8 r1^2 Log[r1]) -
> 2 ArcTan[r1/(2 Rotation) - Rotation/(2 r1)] (Rotation^2 + 8 r1^2 Log[r1])))
> ```

in *Mathematica 9.0.1*, and

> During evaluation of In[35]:= Simplify::time: Time spent on a transformation
>       exceeded 300.` seconds, and the transformation was aborted. Increasing the
>       value of TimeConstraint option may improve the result of simplification. >>
>
> Out[35]= 1/2 Mass Integrate[((r^2 - Rotation^2 (-2 + Cos[θ]^2)) 
>       Sin[θ])/(r^2 + Rotation^2 Cos[θ]^2)^2, {r, r1, ∞}, 
>       {θ, 0, π}, Assumptions -> r1 > 0 && Rotation >= 0]

in *Mathematica 10.0.0*. In the latter case, it takes much longer to return, although it fails to produce the result. Is this a bug?

Comment: Did you try to "_Increasing the value of `TimeConstraint` option may improve the result of simplification._"?

Comment: I didn't, because it takes far longer in Mathematica 10 than in Mathematica 9 for this to return, which seems to be a bug, too.

Comment: OK :) That sounds correct indeed :)

Comment: Now that I tried it without `Simplify`, Mathematica 10 takes twice as long as Mathematica 9 albeit without result. The problem is not that `Simplify` is time-constrained; it is that the integral cannot be calculated.

Comment: I can confirm that I get the same results as the OP. My suggestion would be to report this to support@wolfram.com.

Comment: I get the same results on V9 (86.1 sec) and V10 (84.7 sec), Macbook Pro, OSX 10.9.4

Comment: @auxsvr Can you tell me how you managed to paste code with Greek letters in it - or point me to a reference about that?

Comment: @MitchellKaplan I didn't; @Öskå probably edited my question and replaced `\[Theta]` with $\theta$ etc.

Comment: Now this is getting weird: in v. 10 I get `1/2 Mass (1/r1 + \[Pi]/(2 Rotation) - ArcTan[r1/Rotation]/Rotation + (
   Rotation ArcTan[Rotation/r1])/r1^2)`, which is the correct result and is much more simple than that of v.9, even though I didn't use `Simplify` and nothing, that I'm aware of, changed meanwhile!

Comment: Didnr mathematica10 get a new update system could that be doing work in the background

Comment: Please disregard my previous comment. Mathematica 10 can find the integral if I change the order of integration. Mathematica 9 cannot find it in this case after waiting for tens of minutes.

Comment: @MitchellKaplan Here is a nice tool you can install in order to format your code with Greek letters etc.: [Additional useful buttons for our M.SE editor](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor)

Answer (score 2):

In a few seconds *Mathematica* 7.0.1 under Windows returns:

```
(Mass (r1 Rotation + (r1^2 + Rotation^2) ArcTan[Rotation/r1]))/(2 r1^2 Rotation)
```

On the other hand *Mathematica* 10.0.0 is still working after several minutes.  Assuming the above output is correct this seems like a regression.

Comment: It is correct, thanks. I get three results of varying complexity, depending on the version of Mathematica, and v. 10 cannot solve this if I swap the order of the variables of integration. v.10 after swap and yours give the simplest results. Unfortunately, the simplicity of the result does not remain constant or increase as the version increases, and it is quite obvious that most built-in simplifications do not work for the result I quoted above. Is there a way to configure how `Integrate` calculates the result?